# Creating an Environment to Mimic News Websites

Tags: environments

Sometimes literature and linguistic papers deal with journalistic texts. Therefore researchers need an environment that creates something looking like the [beginning of this link](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/0,1518,806564,00.html) (from the line "Japan" to the last headline of the bold part "zunächst nicht vor"):

I suppose an environment can be created by the use of three arguments (one for the first headline, one for the second headline and one for the bold text) which are specified by colour, font and vertical distance. But I am not able to create it myself. So my question is: Is anyone out there who knows how to create an environment that mirrors the beginning of the article.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? KOMA provides the command `\dictum` and `setchapterpreamble`.

Comment: I use the book documentclass and I want to stick with it, because I already put together large pieces of work and worry that changing to another documentclass will lead to unpleasant results.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{article}[3][]
  {\setkeys{article}{#1}\putplace{#2}\puttitle{#3}}
  {\ifabstract\endgroup\fi\par}
\newcommand{\putplace}[1]{{\noindent\placefont#1\par}\vspace\placespace\@afterindentfalse}
\newcommand{\puttitle}[1]{{\@afterheading\titlefont#1\par}\vspace\titlespace
  \begingroup\abstracttrue\abstractfont\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\newcommand{\startarticle}{\par\endgroup\vspace\abstractspace
  \abstractfalse\@afterheading\articlefont}
\newif\ifabstract

\define@key{article}{placefont}{\def\placefont{#1}}
\define@key{article}{placespace}{\def\placespace{#1}}
\define@key{article}{titlefont}{\def\titlefont{#1}}
\define@key{article}{titlespace}{\def\titlespace{#1}}
\define@key{article}{abstractfont}{\def\abstractfont{#1}}
\define@key{article}{abstractspace}{\def\abstractspace{#1}}
\define@key{article}{articlefont}{\def\articlefont{#1}}
\def\placefont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\def\placespace{3ex}
\def\titlefont{\Large\bfseries}
\def\titlespace{3ex}
\def\abstractfont{\bfseries}
\def\abstractspace{2ex}
\def\articlefont{\normalfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{article}
  {Japan}
  {Schweres Erdbeben erschüttert Tokio}
In Tokio schwankten die Häuser: Die japanische Hauptstadt und der
Osten des Landes sind von einem schweren Erdbeben der Stärke 7,0
erschüttert worden. Das Epizentrum des Bebens lag etwa 560 Kilometer
südlich der Metropole. Eine Tsunami-Warnung wurde jedoch nicht
gegeben. Angaben über Schäden lagen zunächst nicht vor.

\startarticle

Hamburg - Ein starkes Erdbeben hat am Neujahrstag den Osten Japans und
Tokio erschüttert. Das Beben der Stärke 7,0 ereignete sich um 14.28
Uhr Ortszeit (6.28 Uhr MEZ), wie die japanische Erdbebenwarte
mitteilte, und ließ zahlreiche Gebäude in der Hauptstadt
schwanken. Eine Tsunami-Warnung wurde jedoch nicht ausgegeben. Auch
lagen zunächst keine Berichte über Schäden oder Verletzte vor.

Das Zentrum des Bebens lag vor der Küste nahe der unbewohnten Insel
Torishima, etwa 600 Kilometer südlich von Tokio. Im Norden und in der
Mitte des Landes wurden die Schnellzüge für Sicherheitsüberprüfungen
aus dem Fahrplan genommen. Der Betreiber des Atomkraftwerks Fukushima
meldete keine Schäden oder Probleme von dem havarierten Kernkraftwerk,
berichtete der Fernsehsender NHK.

Japan wird regelmäßig von schweren Erdbeben heimgesucht. Am 11. März
hatte ein Erdbeben der Stärke 9,0 einen verheerenden Tsunami
ausgelöst, der weite Teile des Nordostens Japans verwüstete. Fast
20.000 Menschen starben oder gelten als vermisst. Durch die
Naturkatastrophe wurde zudem mit der Beschädigung des Atomkraftwerks
Fukushima eines der schwersten Atomunglücke der Geschichte ausgelöst.
\end{article}

\end{document}
```

For a particularly striking title you can change the font size or color or whatever by means of the defined keywords; for example

```
\begin{article}[titlefont=\Huge\bfseries\color{red}]
  {Japan}
  {Schweres Erdbeben erschüttert Tokio}
```

Defaults for the values are defined above just after the keys.

## EDIT

The following uses the LaTeX3 keyval system. I've added the key `articleindent` that specifies the amount of indentation of the article text and a command `\setuparticle` to set up values different from the default, that can also be specified for each article in the optional argument. The code is a mixture of LaTeX2 and LaTeX3; I'll try to improve it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifabstract
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {article}
  {
   placefont .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_article_placefont_tl { #1 },
   placespace .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_article_placespace_tl { #1 },
   titlefont .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_article_titlefont_tl { #1 },
   titlespace .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_article_titlespace_tl { #1 },
   abstractfont .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_article_abstractfont_tl { #1 },
   abstractspace .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_article_abstractspace_tl { #1 },
   articlefont .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_article_articlefont_tl { #1 },
   articleindent .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_article_articleindent_tl { #1 },
  }

\tl_set:Nn \l_article_placefont_tl {\normalsize\bfseries}
\tl_set:Nn \l_article_placespace_tl {3ex}
\tl_set:Nn \l_article_titlefont_tl {\Large\bfseries}
\tl_set:Nn \l_article_titlespace_tl {3ex}
\tl_set:Nn \l_article_abstractfont_tl {\bfseries}
\tl_set:Nn \l_article_abstractspace_tl {2ex}
\tl_set:Nn \l_article_articlefont_tl {\normalfont}
\tl_set:Nn \l_article_articleindent_tl {\parindent}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{article}{O{}mm}
  {
   \keys_set:nn {article} {#1}
   \article_putplace:n {#2}
   \article_puttitle:n {#3}
  }
  {\ifabstract\endgroup\else\end{list}\fi\par}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setuparticle}{m}
  {\keys_set:nn {article} {#1}}

\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn \article_putplace:n #1 
  {
   {\noindent \l_article_placefont_tl #1 \par}
    \vspace\l_article_placespace_tl 
    \@afterindentfalse
  }
\cs_new:Npn \article_puttitle:n #1 
  {
   {\@afterheading\l_article_titlefont_tl #1 \par}
    \vspace\l_article_titlespace_tl
    \group_begin: 
    \abstracttrue
    \l_article_abstractfont_tl
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\startarticle}{}
  {
   \par
   \group_end:
   \vspace\l_article_abstractspace_tl
   \abstractfalse
   \l_article_articlefont_tl
   \begin{list}{}{%
         \topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt
         \leftmargin=\l_article_articleindent_tl
         \rightmargin=\l_article_articleindent_tl
         \parsep=0pt
         \itemindent=0pt
         \listparindent=\parindent
    }\item\relax
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{article}[titlespace=10ex,titlefont=\Huge\bfseries]
  {Japan}
  {Schweres Erdbeben erschüttert Tokio}
In Tokio schwankten die Häuser: Die japanische Hauptstadt und der
Osten des Landes sind von einem schweren Erdbeben der Stärke 7,0
erschüttert worden. Das Epizentrum des Bebens lag etwa 560 Kilometer
südlich der Metropole. Eine Tsunami-Warnung wurde jedoch nicht
gegeben. Angaben über Schäden lagen zunächst nicht vor.

\startarticle
Hamburg - Ein starkes Erdbeben hat am Neujahrstag den Osten Japans und
Tokio erschüttert. Das Beben der Stärke 7,0 ereignete sich um 14.28
Uhr Ortszeit (6.28 Uhr MEZ), wie die japanische Erdbebenwarte
mitteilte, und ließ zahlreiche Gebäude in der Hauptstadt
schwanken. Eine Tsunami-Warnung wurde jedoch nicht ausgegeben. Auch
lagen zunächst keine Berichte über Schäden oder Verletzte vor.

Das Zentrum des Bebens lag vor der Küste nahe der unbewohnten Insel
Torishima, etwa 600 Kilometer südlich von Tokio. Im Norden und in der
Mitte des Landes wurden die Schnellzüge für Sicherheitsüberprüfungen
aus dem Fahrplan genommen. Der Betreiber des Atomkraftwerks Fukushima
meldete keine Schäden oder Probleme von dem havarierten Kernkraftwerk,
berichtete der Fernsehsender NHK.

Japan wird regelmäßig von schweren Erdbeben heimgesucht. Am 11. März
hatte ein Erdbeben der Stärke 9,0 einen verheerenden Tsunami
ausgelöst, der weite Teile des Nordostens Japans verwüstete. Fast
20.000 Menschen starben oder gelten als vermisst. Durch die
Naturkatastrophe wurde zudem mit der Beschädigung des Atomkraftwerks
Fukushima eines der schwersten Atomunglücke der Geschichte ausgelöst.
\end{article}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are familar with LaTeX 3. I am very interested in a LaTeX 3 solution which uses the `l3keys` package instead of `\define@key` ;-) Happy new year.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I've not studied that part, yet. :)

Comment: Yet is a goog word. It is awesome how fast you have learned the new syntax.

Comment: @egreg: Thx! It works perfectly. However, when I used it, I thought that it might be an advantage when the journalistic mimic  would be in contrast to the other parts of the text. For example, by indenting the journalistic part on both sides. Do you know how to add a feature like that?

Comment: @Philip See edit.

Answer (score 5):

Creating an environment for such text, is probably unecessary, rather use commands, similar to LaTeX's section, chapter and other similar control sequences.

Before you start with defining commands, is best to just try and develop the code using just LaTeX raw commands. The example that follows does just this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt

{\Large\bfseries \textcolor{gray}{Japan}}
\medskip

{\Large\textcolor{purple}{Schweres Erdbeben erschüttert Tokio}}
\medskip

{\large \bfseries In Tokio schwankten die Häuser: Die japanische Hauptstadt 
  und der Osten des Landes sind von einem schweren Erdbeben der Stärke 7,0 
  erschüttert worden. Das Epizentrum des Bebens lag etwa 560 Kilometer 
  südlich der Metropole. Eine Tsunami-Warnung wurde jedoch nicht gegeben. 
  Angaben über Schäden lagen zunächst nicht vor.}

\end{document}
```

Once you get the sizing and everything the way you want it, you can then change everything into commands. For example the first heading, can be defined as:

```
\newcommand{\smallheading}[2][\Large\bfseries\color{gray}]{
  \bgroup#1#2\egroup 
}
```

You should name your commands in some sort of semantic manner and not like I did above. Maybe, `\countryarticle`, `\summary` etc.

Comment: I would make an environment out of it which accepts the first two headlines as arguments and then takes the message as body: `\begin{news}{Japan}{Schweres Erdbeben erschüttert Tokio} In Tokio .. nicht vor. \end{news}`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks for the comment. Personally I tend to view these type of problems as sectioning commands and try to keep a consistent UI with the rest of LaTeX. It is also easier to extend if you start thinking of star commands and adding to `toc`. But environment can work equally well.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: This works equally well. I cant exactly say, why I prefer the solution based on the environment. I suppose it is my feeling that general changes in the layout are achievable more userfriendly when writing larger documents containing lots of website news examples.